# on size change remove the existing image and add other image dynamically without reloading the page

Tags: php, html, json, ajax

I am building a website. In that I am using bootstrap carousel in which I am adding images dynamically according to the orientation of the screen.

1. By JavaScript I am measuring the width and height of the screen and posting the width, height, and id to the php via ajax.
2. in php the width, height, id is received, php is fetching all the data from the mysql table with respect to the id.
3. if width is greater then height then it is landscape orientation and it converts all the values under landscape column into json.
4. Otherwise it is portrait orientation and it converts all the values under portrait column into json.
5. The ajax calls back the json data and appends it to the data correctly.

My problem is while the screen is in landscape mode it shows all the landscape images (example 5 images). When the orientation is changed to portrait the ajax works and fetches the portrait images (example 5 images) and adds to the existing landscape images resulting in 10 images. If i change the orientation again, landscape images are added again resulting in 15 images. After refreshing the page only 5 images are shown with respect to the orientation.

How to get this without refreshing the page (when the orientation is changed from landscape to portrait, all landscape images should be removed and portrait images should be added without refreshing the page).

```html
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body onresize="send_screen_size()" onload="send_screen_size()">
<div class="container">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" >
    <div class="carousel-inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
function send_screen_size(sParam){

    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++)
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam)
        {
            return decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[1]);
        }
    }



    if(window.innerWidth !== undefined && window.innerHeight !== undefined) {
                 var w = window.innerWidth;
                 var h = window.innerHeight;
             } else {
                 var w = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
                 var h = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
            }
            var 
            width =  + w ;
            height =  + h;

    var width = width =  + w ;
    var height = height =  + h;
    var pro_id = send_screen_size('pro_id');

 $.ajax({
    async : "false", // !!!MAKE SURE THIS ONE IS SET!!!
    type:"POST",
    url: "carousel.php",
    data:{width: width, height: height, pro_id:pro_id},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data){
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
    $('.carousel-inner').append('<div class = item>'+item.orientation+'</div>')
      })
    $('.carousel-inner > :first-child').addClass("active");
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
      console.log(error);
    }

   });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
$('.carousel-inner .item').remove();
```

before $.ajax call.

You might want to throttle or debounce your window onresize event listener also.